# VM with VLAN trunk on KVM

Tags: networking, 18.04, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

What exactly do I need to configure on Ubuntu18-based QEMU/KVM server to pass a trunk with >1 VLANs to a VM on it? (basically the equivalent of setting VLAN ID to 4095 on a port with ESXi) Some rather complex examples of reportedly achieving that by means of 1 main and >1 aux bridges that I've seen so far don't look optimal at a glance... unless it's the only feasible way with KVM. Many thanks in advance!

Update: It seems like no matter what I do my VLANs aren't showing up as active at the remote end of the trunk attached to a Cisco Nexus 9k switch despite they're all enabled on the switch trunk and defined on the switch itself. A pcap trace taken at the Linux host shows a bunch of *tagged* STP RST packets arriving from the switch (one per VLAN defined on the switch) and only one *untagged* STP Conf sent by Linux right after (unsure if in response or not). Is that expected? What is the very minimal VLAN aware Linux trunk bridge config w/o any virtualization stuff involved that would let me verify basic VLAN trunk operation between my Linux host and the switch for a start? Would something like defining a bridge on that host interface and creating a VLAN on that bridge suffice?

Comment: You don't need >1 bridges, you just need one that passes all traffic and that can be done either with a [bridge](https://blog.davidvassallo.me/2012/05/05/kvm-brctl-in-linux-bringing-vlans-to-the-guests/) in manual or netplan setup and then [connected to guest via libvirt](https://netplan.io/examples/#configuring-network-bridges) - or you can directly up the gears a bit (depending on what you eventually need/do) and use [OVS](https://blog.scottlowe.org/2013/05/28/vlan-trunking-to-guest-domains-with-open-vswitch/) which again is just one bridge. Does this solve your need?

Comment: Many thanks @Christian Ehrhardt : let me read it all and try it here. Will get back once done.

Comment: @ChristianEhrhardt: No luck here with a single manually created bridge as per "Homerun: going to guest trunk mode" at https://blog.davidvassallo.me/2012/05/05/kvm-brctl-in-linux-bringing-vlans-to-the-guests/ and even with several manually created bridges as per "A lengthy solution" at https://serverfault.com/questions/543434/multiple-different-vlan-trunks-to-kvm-guests-linux/543682#543682 . A detailed response doesn't fit in here, so I'll try entering it as an update to my OP above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ChristianEhrhardt who pointed me in the right direction we managed to work out the right config here. To my surprise even defining any VLANs on the KVM host's "trunk" bridge as suggested at one of those links wasn't necessary. All we had to do was add a bridge with the KVM host's trunk interface in it:

```
brctl addbr br2
brctl addif br2 enp94s0f0
```

and then put guest's "trunk" NIC into that bridge using virt-manager GUI and then create as many subinterfaces on that guest as VLANs on that trunk. I couldn't think of anything easier than that as it seems the bridge becomes "VLAN aware" automatically somehow.